# How to add try to a function in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, error-handling

I have this void function that retrieve me some data but I want to catch the errors so I tried to use try but couldn't so does anyone know what to do :) .

```
void getUserData() async {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    firestoreInstance
        .collection("Students")
        .document(usernameController.text)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        email = (value.data)['email'];
        password = (value.data)['password'];
        gender = (value.data)['gender'];
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your code in `try`: Dart [allows `await`ed calls to throw exceptions as usual](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#handling-errors):

```dart
void getUserData() async {
  try {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    firestoreInstance
        .collection("Students")
        .document(usernameController.text)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        email = (value.data)['email'];
        password = (value.data)['password'];
        gender = (value.data)['gender'];
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // Recover
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using then you could await that Future<T> as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use try and catch like this

```dart
void getUserData() async {
    try{
      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      firestoreInstance
          .collection("Students")
          .document(usernameController.text)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          email = (value.data)['email'];
          password = (value.data)['password'];
          gender = (value.data)['gender'];
        });
      });
    }catch(e){
      //do something with the error
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond and the solution.